# NSTimer Without Initial Delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Is there a way to remove the initial delay on an `NSTimer`? The following code is for my timer, which is all fine.

```
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

However, the method does not run for the first 5 seconds. I would like my method (`updateTime`) to run on the following timeline from 00:00:00 when the app is opened.

- 00:00:00 - Run Method
- 00:00:05 - Run Method
- 00:00:10 - Run Method

Currently, it only does:

- 00:00:05 - Run Method
- 00:00:10 - Run Method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make a timer fire before its time interval has elapsed, but you can do this:

```
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[self updateTime];
```

Comment: so it runs once from the self and from then on from the nstimer

Comment: Right. You send the message the first time, and the timer will take care of sending subsequent messages every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this simple Line

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just call fire() Api as soon as you set the object; it will start directly without delay thereby solving your problem. Check the uploaded image for reference.